# Diagnosing SSH Connection Issues

Tags: linux, networking, ssh

So we recently have done some IT restructuring for one our server networks. I am able to generally ssh to the machine, but usually within a small time frame (< 1 min) the SSH connection is dropped with the following error message:

```
Write failed: Connection reset by peer
```

Sometimes my SSH command is just outright refused as well:

```
ssh: connect to host myserver.com port 22: Connection refused
```

This is making server adminstration tricky to say the least. Unfortunately I am not very well versed in IT and so I am unsure how to try and figure out what is causing the issue. I have looked at the SSH connection settings on the machine and they appear to be normal.

How can I go about tracing the problem?

Verbose Output:

Failed Connection:

```
ssh -v user@myserver.com
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Connecting to myserver.com [ip.ip.ip.ip] port 22.
debug1: connect to address ip.ip.ip.ip port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host myserver.com port 22: Connection timed out
```

Dropped Connection:

There is a ton of info printed out when first connecting, but when the connection is dropped all that is printed is:

```
Write failed: Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: This doesn't sound like a SSH-specific problem (try pinging the server immediately when the connection fails, just to check). You might want to try this: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1402929&p=8804585#post8804585

Comment: Once connected, do SSH sessions drop only when left idle, or always? In the former case, you might consider setting `ServerAliveInterval` in `~/.ssh/config` (see `man ssh_config` for more).

Comment: In general SSH is TCP and hence never dropped, even when idle. But are you maybe passing through any kind of firewall, e.g. with NAT? You may want to try setting `keepalive` in the ssh configuration. Though this has nothing to do with the connection refused issue ... Is the server under heavy load (networkwise)?

Comment: @AaronMiller Always, even while in use.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen It is not under heavy load no. It is a server I use for development, and after some network changes is behaving very poorly. I am starting to think that it may be a routing issue.

Comment: So what changes have you introduced?

Comment: @tink Moved it behind a new load balancer. Also put it in a different subnet of the switch.